# Apache Cordova (PhoneGap) iOS Video Capture Overlay View

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm modifying an app that I had no involvement in initially building, implementing some additional video capture features. The app is built entirely using Cordova with a ruby back end. The video features I need to add require an overlay to be placed above the video capture view containing some text. Is this possible using Cordova, I know it's possible in native iOS apps.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible if you create a phonegap plugin to add the overlay, not possible with html code.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for this. I've not worked with Cordova before so still getting used to it. Have started to build a plugin to take care of this.

Comment: Did you succeed? Care to share the plugin with the community? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/VideoCapturePlus-PhoneGap-Plugin) is what you're looking for. Custom overlay is only supported for iOS in the current version of the plugin (according to the description).